# Fetching the required fields in the different documents from multiple collections in mongoDB for Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I want to construct a complex query using multiple collections in `mongoDB`. Below is my sample `SQL` query.

```
SELECT *
FROM bands    AS b
    JOIN gigs     AS g ON g.bandid = b.bandid
    JOIN members  AS m ON m.bandid = b.bandid
    JOIN comments AS c ON c.bandid = b.bandid
    JOIN tracks   AS t ON t.bandid = b.bandid
WHERE b.bandid = URL.id;
```

How to write the equivalent query for the above `sql` query in `mongodb` using multiple collections(10)?

Comment: From the newer Mongo 3.2, you can perform joins. But only left outer joins, using aggregate function. Refer this page: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: If you need to join 5 collections in the "daily business" of your application, you should really reconsider your data model.

Comment: @Nattyk can you explain a little further how a left outer join will happen with aggregation?